# Best way to pipe audio and video chunks from within python to ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, named-pipes, webm

**Problem**

I'm getting audio and video chunks from a third-party server and I would like to pipe those chunks to ffmpeg to create a WebM live stream according to these instructions:

http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-do-webm-live-streaming-via-dash

Here they are using input from webcam and microphone but I need to use the data chunks, so the ffmpeg command would look somehow like this:

```
    cmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-f", "flv", "-i", "video.fifo",
        "-f", "s16le", "-ar", "16000", "-ac", "1", "-i", "audio.fifo",
        "-map", "0:0",
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        "-c:v", "libvpx-vp9",
        "-s", "640x480", "-keyint_min", "40", "-g", "40", "-speed", "6",
        "-tile-columns", "4", "-frame-parallel", "1", "-threads", "8",
        "-static-thresh", "0", "-max-intra-rate", "300",
        "-deadline", "realtime", "-lag-in-frames", "0",
        "-error-resilient", "1",
        "-b:v", "3000k",
        "-f", "webm_chunk",
        "-header", self.video_header,
        "-chunk_start_index", "1",
        "video_360_%d.chk",
        "-map", "1:0",
        "-c:a", "libvorbis",
        "-b:a", "16k", "-ar", "16000",
        "-f", "webm_chunk",
        "-audio_chunk_duration", "2000",
        "-header", self.audio_header,
        "-chunk_start_index", "1",
        "audio_171_%d.chk"
    ]
```

As you can see, I am using a "video.fifo" and "audio.fifo" file, because I thought it would be a good idea to pipe the chunks in via a named pipe, but I can't get it to work. Here is what I'm doing:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
fa = os.open("video.fifo", os.O_WRONLY)
fv = os.open("audio.fifo", os.O_WRONLY)
```

So I'm starting the subprocess first, so that it opens the fifo files for reading. After that, I should be able to open them for writing but I am not. More specifically, I am able to open the first one, but not the second one. So maybe that has something to do with how ffmpeg handles its inputs if there are more than one, but I just don't know.

**Question**

How can I either solve the problem of non openable named pipes or how can I achieve what I wanted to achieve without named pipes.

Comment: I exactly want to achieve this and send raw video/audio to two different pipes as sending them to one causes my video to be weird and still without sound!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in your link advise running ffmpeg in the background. From the ffmpeg man page:

> -stdin
>
> Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless standard input is used as an input. To explicitly disable interaction you need to specify "**-nostdin**".
>
> Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if ffmpeg is in the background process group. Roughly the same result can be achieved with "ffmpeg ... **< /dev/null**" but it requires a shell.

I had a similar issue not too long ago. When handling multiple inputs ffmpeg would work as expected the first time and then start throwing errors every time after that. Adding `-nostdin` to your global arguments or `</dev/null` should correct the problem. Stripped of all the bells and whistles, either of the following should work.

`ffmpeg [in-args][input][out-args][output] & </dev/null`

`ffmpeg [-nostdin in-args][input][out-args][output] &`

Hope this helps.